# 1px glitch in Chrome with floats

Tags: google-chrome, css-float

I am trying to create a photo gallery grid layout using floats (3 per row), the image thumbnails seem that they align nicely in Firefox and IE across the wrapper but on Chrome there's a 1 pixel margin to the right, is there any way to fix this behavior?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
.wrap{
    width:900px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrap div{
    float:left;
    width:295px;
    height:200px;
    background:#333;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:0.469em;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(3n+3){ /* wont work in IE8 */
    margin-right:0;
}

.clear:before, .clear:after{ content:""; display:table; }
.clear:after{ clear:both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap clear">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="margin-right:0;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="margin-right:0;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="margin-right:0;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>​
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't see it. Maybe it's fixed by now?

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. Possibly was a rounding bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not occur in latest version of Chrome (currently 23.0.1271.64 m - Windows), was possibly a rounding bug.